# Binet's Fibonacci Number Formula on the (real) Cartesian plane

Tags: functions, complex-numbers, coordinate-systems, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

Binet's Fibonacci Number Formula $\frac{φ^{n}-(-φ)^{-n}}{\sqrt 5}$ produces a sine-like curve for positive numbers and a spiral for negative numbers when plotted on a complex plane (see figs. 1., and 2.)

I'd like to know the parametric equations of this curve on the (real) Cartesian plane. In other words, the exact translation of this curve on to the Cartesian plane written in terms of $x(t),$ and $y(t)$.

[fig. 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Ubk.png)

[fig. 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jWFs.png)

Comment: How exactly do you define your path? I suppose you want to do something with $\gamma : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ where $$\gamma(t) = \frac{\varphi^t -(-\varphi)^{-t}}{\sqrt 5}, $$ but that gives you a few possibilities when rewriting $(-\varphi)^{-t} = \exp(-t \operatorname{Log}(-\varphi))$, as for negative numbers we don't have "the standard branch" to chose from. Some may say it should be one corresponding to argument of $\pi$, but $-\pi$ is just as good, and there are infinitely many others

Comment: @Esgeriath Thank you!

You can use any definition you want so long as a result yields identical geometry, ie., if the two planes and their curves are superimposed, every point on the one curve should match the one on the other curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets define differentiable paths $\gamma_k:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ so that they "match" formula

$$\gamma(t) = \frac{\varphi^t -(-\varphi)^{-t}}{\sqrt 5},$$
where $\varphi = \frac{1 + \sqrt 5}2$ is the golden ratio.
To do so, use formula for exponentiation of complex numbers:
$z^w = \exp(w\log(z))$ where $\log$ is the complex natural logarithm multi-function. We have
$$\log\varphi = \ln \varphi + 2l\pi \mathrm i\,,\quad\log(-\varphi) = \ln\varphi + (2k + 1)\pi\mathrm i$$ where $\ln : (0, \infty) \to \mathbb R$ is the real natural logarithm function, and $k,l\in \mathbb Z$. Since $\varphi$ is positive real number, I will assume that $l = 0$, and complex logarithm is the same as real one for it.

Using Euler's formula we can write
\begin{align}
\gamma_k(t) &= \frac{\exp(t\ln\varphi) -
\exp(-t\ln\varphi -t(2k+1)\pi\mathrm i)}{\sqrt 5} \\
&= \frac {\exp(t\ln\varphi) - 
\exp(-t\ln\varphi)\cos((2k+1)\pi t)} {\sqrt 5}
+ \mathrm i \frac{\exp(-t\ln\varphi)\sin((2k + 1)\pi t)}{\sqrt 5}.
\end{align}
Looking at real and imaginary parts we obtain family of curves that satisfy initial assumptions:
$$ \begin{cases}
x_k(t) = \frac {\varphi^t - 
\varphi^{-t}\cos((2k+1)\pi t)} {\sqrt 5}\\
y_k(t) = \frac{\varphi^{-t}\sin((2k + 1)\pi t)}{\sqrt 5}
\end{cases}.
$$
If you [plot](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dpvxzbgvtg) them you can see that your geometry is matched when $k=-1$ (it is a bit distorted, I think your first plot may have different scales on the axis).